# Freeze after computer suspends for the first time in a session

Tags: suspend

This problem started today. I can boot my computer into Ubuntu fine after logging in. If I leave my computer alone, it "suspends" (screen darkens, etc). I move my mouse to awaken my computer, and I am at the login screen. I put in my password, and I hit enter, and the button grays out, but I don't go anywhere. I can move my mouse, but nothing responds to mouse clicks. I can however go into terminal though, so its not a complete freeze...

Regarding my system, I have:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1500 X Quad-Core Processor x 8
- Graphics: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
- Base system: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit
- GNOME Shell 3.18.5

I'm able to provide more information if anything thinks it will be helpful (but I'm a newbie so it might take a bit of handholding to provide that information). I've tried a solution someone suggested where I switch display drivers from "Using X.Org X Server" to the NVIDIA binary driver, but that didn't seem to work.

### Additional Drivers

[image: Addtional Drivers]

Comment: Your AMD CPU includes an excellent GPU: https://www.pcgamesn.com/amd/amd-ryzen-5-1500x-review-benchmarks so I would first eliminate the Nvidia 1050 being the source of the problem by rebooting using the built-in GPU.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I open "Additional drivers" this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/D2aIh5P.png. The AMD isn't really in the same category as the NVIDIA, so I wouldn't have thought there to be a conflict on that end. Are you suggesting that I select button 1 for the 3rd option, and perhaps button 2 for the 2nd option?

Comment: Your image was most helpful. I moved it from the comments into your question. The first thing I would do is enable the third option - AMD microcode. This *could* fix things all on it's own.

Comment: That did the trick (although it looks like I need to resinstall some applications and GNOME extensions)! Thank you very much.  For the 2nd option, do you have an idea of which I should put it towards (NVIDIA or the X.Org.X one?)

Comment: For the second option you should experiment what works best for you. If neither option causes system freezes then I'd run benchmark tests to see which is the fastest. Obviously if one option causes freezes then you would use the other. In the mean time, I'll write an answer so this question can be taken off the `unanswered question` list if you are so inclined to accept the answer.

Comment: Will do. It turns out by the way that my extensions were just turned off, and applications didn't actually go away.  So everything is pretty good. 

I accept the answer too. How do I shut down a thread/how do I "honor" you?

Comment: When you read **any** question or answer you think is good you click the "chevron" or up-arrow beside it. When you ask a question and it is answered you can up-vote the answer as well. The author of a question can select the best answer for him/her and click the check mark next to it.

Comment: Noted and check-marked :)

Comment: Thank you and ***Welcome to Ask Ubutnu*** :) I also upvoted your question which earns you 5 points and equally as important may help others with the same problem. When they see an upvoted question they know it's a good one and take the time to read it along with answers below it. I encourage you to search for other questions on this site to learn more about your hardware, Ubuntu and using Linux in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many circumstances it is best to install AMD microcode firmware to address "glitches". In your case it is the third option on the sample screen.

On Intel platforms such as mine it reads:

```
Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from Intel-microcode (proprietary)
```

To access this screen (whether on AMD or Intel CPU, or whether using Nvidia GPU or Radeon GPU) use:

- Select `System Settings` (the gear icon from the launcher)
- Select `Software and Updates`
- Select `Additional Drivers`